# Powershell Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I wrote this script to execute commands on a remote machine.
If I inkove it with no parameters it runs fine

```
PS D:\batch>  .\remoteExecute.ps1 -computer myServer -command 'dir'

Directory: C:\Users\AC0476BF\Documents

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                  PSComputerName                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                  --------------
-----        5/31/2021   4:27 PM                WindowsPowerShell                     myServer                  

Executing: 'dir' on remote computer myServer
```

However if I specify a parameter it returns an error.

```
PS D:\batch>  .\remoteExecute.ps1 -computer myserver -command 'dir c:\windows'
The term 'dir c:\windows' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dir c:\windows:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : myServer
 
Executing: 'dir c:\windows' on remote computer myServer
```

**What am I missing?**

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Remote computer")]
    [String]$computer, 
        
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Command to be executed on the remote computer")]
    [String]$command, 
        
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, HelpMessage = "Logging of command enabled to filename specified")]
    [String]$logFile,
        
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, HelpMessage = "Execute in Command Shell. Default is PowerShell")]
    [Switch]$cmdShell
)
 
try {
    if ($cmdShell) {
        $command = "cmd --% /c '" + $command + "'"
    }

    if ($logFile) {
        $executeCommand = $command + " *>> " + $logfile
    }
    else {
        $executeCommand = $command
    }

    Invoke-Command -computerName $computer -ScriptBlock { & $using:executeCommand } 
                
    $message = "Executing: '" + $executeCommand + "' on remote computer " + $computer
    Write-Host $message

   
    exit 0
}
catch {
    $message = $PSItem.ToString()
    Write-Host $message
    # logging goes here...
    throw     
}
```

Comment: Either change `-ScriptBlock { & $using:executeCommand }` -> `-ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($using:executeCommand))`, or define a separate parameter for the arguments

Comment: Hi @MathiasR.Jessen. Thanks for the help. I've changed to ```-ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create($using:executeCommand)) ``` and now it returns A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer

Comment: My bad, remove the `using:` part entirely

Comment: It worked. Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen